# Setting up a cookie with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, cookies

My app have this need to set a "cookie" for user preference. My app have a tour feature, which when user has viewed it it should not show up again, there is a onDone method for the tour and I am thinking of saving a cookie one this method is triggered.

However, doing `Cookies.setCookiet("myapp-tour-done", "yes");` does not work. Am I missing something? Or is this the even the right approach?

Comment: There is a typo: Cookies.setCookie**t**("myapp-tour-done", "yes"); If the typo is not the problem could you tell us what the problem is ? Do you mean the cookie is not saved or that you can't retrieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be having a problem with the domain. You should try to isolate the case where it works and where it doesn't, i.e. do a Cookies.getCookie("myapp-tour-done") directly after you set it.

If your application changes domains (i.e. from example.com to myapp.example.com) or hierarchy (example.com/bigscope to example.com/bigscope/smallscope) there might be issues with cookie permissions. This means that if your application sets a cookie in one domain or hierarchy, it might not be readable from another one.

You can read up more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970178.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened but I just moved the saving of cookie from the EntryPoint class into some other page and it works fine now.